# "Print this post"

Tags: script

Answer to [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/128703/can-i-print-a-single-answer).

Adds a "print" link to *individual* posts. Does not do any stripping down of markup, the post is preserved as-is. The rest of the page is eaten by the jQuery monster.

### Installation

- [Click here to install](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/PrintPost.user.js). Will only work in Chrome or Firefox (the latter requires Greasemonkey).  See [this page](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) if you have trouble.
- [Source](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/PrintPost.user.js)

### Screenshots

[image]

Original:
[image]

Printed:
[image]

Comment: Given the CC-attribution-required, I'd like the author's name to be on the print too. Other than that: nice!

Comment: Oh wow... yea... that works fantastically well! You might want to put a margin on the resulting div - it's hugging the left side of my screen ever so tightly...

Comment: @Arjan will do tomorrow.. I'll keep the gravatar out though..

Comment: @Lix It won't make a diff when printing (if anything, it'll use more space), but it looks ugly, yeah. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @Arjan Here ya go https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/d123e5e9ef3bd61c41369c631dabd9bb17b5b8a0/StackExchange/PrintPost.user.js Should it add the userid as well? (That may look ugly)

Comment: @Lix see above..

Comment: For those who clicking on PRINT does NOT work:
Click on GreaseMonkey -> Manage Userscripts
Right Click on Print-A-Post and select "Edit".
Delete the word ".owner" from this line:
usernameprint=$(this).closest('div.question,div[id^=answer]').find("td.post-signature div.user-details a")[0].innerHTML;
Now it should work again.
Sorry i don't have enough reputation to put this to the right spot.

Comment: I've updated the script to fix the script to work with the current version of the site (td is not used anymore for the post-signature) and also let the script run on https sites [here](https://github.com/raedwa01/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/PrintPost.user.js)

Answer (score 2):

Changelog:

1.0.1:

- Add tiny margin (15px) 'cos it looks ugly
- Sign post with username (for the CC-attribution)

1.0.2:

- Add confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Please oh please will you add a confirmation after clicking the print link.  It is situated so close to the (*much used*) flag link :

[image]

[image]

Possibly a "return to original post" button (but that would show up on the printed version) so might not be a feasible option.